# Browser Seems To Be Looping With Firestore onAuthStateChanged Web Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

From the index.html page there is an option to login.
If the login is successful, then I want to move them to another page (dashboard.html)
If they logout, then they are moved back to index.html

To track whether someone is logged in or not, I am using the onAuthStateChanged()

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {


if (user) {
    console.log('user is signed in', user);
    window.location.assign('dashboard.html');

} else {
    console.log('user is NOT signed in');
    window.location = 'index.html';

}
 })
```

The issue I am having is that the browser appears to be going round in an endless loop.
Anyone have any thoughts on this please

Comment: Can you share complete JS that runs on both of the pages?

Comment: There is quite a bit of js. Are you thinking that there may be a conflict ?

Comment: There might be something that's causing those endless redirects. It might be easier to spot if you share and and we can try running it locally.

Comment: I managed to fond some offending code in one of the other pages, thanks.